# How to add a margin for a y axis that uses symbolic y values

Tags: bar-chart

I want to create a horizontal bar graph using symbolic y labels. However I:

- want to have the bars next to each other (i.e., no space between)
- I want some margin below and above the first and last bar for readability

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
      axis y line=center,
      axis x line=center,
      bar width=4pt,
      bar shift=0pt,
      y=4pt,
      nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
      symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
    ]
      \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (-58,A) (-45,B) (-43,C) };

      \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {
        (19,D)
        (35,E)
        (65,F)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Currently it looks like this and any `height` specifications are changed into `width` specifications.

[image]

Comment: This question has been [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634355/74950) in a unrelated question. I made a comment below the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=left,
    axis y line=center,
    enlargelimits={lower, 0.2},
%
    xbar=11pt,
    bar shift=0pt,  
    y=11pt,
%
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize},
%
      symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
      ytick=\empty,
    ]
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (-58,A) (-45,B) (-43,C) };
\addplot[fill=red]  coordinates { (19,D)  (35,E)  (65,F) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```