# Change nodes near coords value to symbolic y value

Tags: bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I want to have label each bar of a horizontal bar chart with its corresponding y value. However, I am only able to get the numeric representation but not the actual symbolic value.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
      axis y line=center,
      axis x line=center,
      bar width=4pt,
      bar shift=0pt,  %% <-- added                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      y=4pt,
      visualization depends on={y \as \rawy},
      nodes near coords={\rawy},, nodes near coords align={horizontal}, nodes near coords style={font=\tiny},
      symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
      yticklabels=\empty,
    ]
      \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (-58,A) (-45,B) (-43,C) };

      \addplot[fill=red] coordinates {
        (19,D)
        (35,E)
        (65,F)
      };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result with the presumably internal representations for the different y ticks used as the labels instead of the intended symbolic values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit (1):**

- If I correctly understood your question, in nodes near coordinate nodes like to have symbolic coordinates. Do I'm right?

**Edit (2):**

- Your attempt to read data from rows doesn't work since your data are not organized as table (with rows and columns).
- With collecting data in simple table (instead writing them by coordinates), the solution is quite simple.
- Use of tables I see as an advantages and not as a disadvantages. I'm confident, that tables is simpler to automatic generate than collect coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=left,
    axis y line=center,
    enlargelimits={lower, 0.2},
%
    xbar=11pt,
    bar shift=0pt,  
%
    xtick={-80,-60,...,60},
    ytick=\empty,
    y=11pt,
%
    symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
                ]
\addplot[fill=blue!70, 
         nodes near coords style={font=\small, anchor=east},
        ] table[meta=Y] {
                            X   Y
                          -58   A
                          -45   B
                          -43   C
                                };
\addplot[fill=red,
         nodes near coords style={font=\small, anchor=west},
        ] table[meta=Y]  {  
                            X   Y   
                            19  D 
                            35  E 
                            56  F 
                                };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this does not answer my question. I want to have the symbolic values, i.e., A,B,C as the label of the bars.

Comment: However, you solved [another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634342/how-to-add-a-margin-for-a-y-axis-that-uses-symbolic-y-values) by fixing those pesky margins.

Comment: aha, i just looking image in question. Coordinates name I will correct ASAP (late evening, now I'm going on a way now), for now I left answer as it is, and copy it to your other question.

Comment: @Sim, see edited answer. Do I  now correctly figured out what you after?

Comment: yes you did (+1). However, is there a simpler solution than to define a table? I would like keep working with coordinates as it is easier to auto generate the required tex code.

Comment: @Simm see edit 2 of answer. What you after is not possible (at least with my knowledge)  achieve by using of coordinates.

Comment: you are probably right about the tables. However, my current code uses coordinates. I will have to bite that bullet I guess.